# Scrolling TableLayoutPanel to button click

Tags: c#

I set this to make the scrollbar invisble to my tablelayoutpanel:

```
        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = false;
        tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

How Can I set to button click scrolling to right and left?
I tried this:
`int change = tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value + tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange * 40;  tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(change, 0);`
but it's scrolled only once time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way instead:

```
    int change = tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange * 40;
    tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition.X) + change , 0);
```

We need `Math.Abs()` since the values returned by [AutoScrollPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition?view=netcore-3.1) are negative.

Comment: You know how I can get the max scrollbar value to set button enable?

Comment: No idea, sorry.